# Regex usage in C++/CLI

Tags: regex, visual-c++, c++-cli

```
String^ matchStr = "eu";
String^ tempHeader;

for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
{
    tempHeader = gcnew String(header[i].c_str());
    if (Regex::Match(tempHeader, matchStr, RegexOptions::IgnoreCase))
    {
        index = i;
    }
}
```

The above is the code I am trying to use for a Regular Expression, but regardless, it enters into the "IF" loop, and sets index = i.

Comment: Why are you using regex? A simple `indexOf` would be better, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the call returns a `Match` object, and it is not `NULL`. You need to check the `Success` property:

```
if (Regex::Match(tempHeader, matchStr, RegexOptions::IgnoreCase)->Success)
{
    index = i;
}
```

Comment: ->Success did it! Thank you. Wouldn't it be great if C++ help files told you the PROPER way to use these things?

Comment: Can I use ->!Success? I now need to check if my header line does not contain something.

Comment: @user1187621 You cannot put `!` between the `->` and the name of the property. You need to move it all the way outside of the expression: `if (!Regex::Match(tempHeader, matchStr, RegexOptions::IgnoreCase)->Success)
`

Comment: How would I do something like:
`while (getline(mcFile, line) && !Regex::Match(line, sepStr, RegexOptions::IgnoreCase)->Success))`